# Returning passed parameter as column in result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure code working and want to add the passed parameter `@tabname` as a column in the result set.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CountStar 
    @Tabname char(10)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SQL varchar(250)

    SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT ETL_LAST_UPD_DTTM, COUNT(*) FROM ls.' + QuoteName(@Tabname) +
    'GROUP BY ETL_LAST_UPD_DTTM'
    EXEC (@SQL)

    SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT ETL_LAST_UPD_DTTM, COUNT(*) FROM ci.' + QuoteName(@Tabname) +
    'GROUP BY ETL_LAST_UPD_DTTM'
    EXEC (@SQL)
    --COMMIT
END
GO
```

Currently this will return the last updated timestamp and the record count for the table being passed into the stored procedure for the 2 schemas identified. I want to add the `@tabname` to the result set as the first column followed by last updated timestamp and the record counts. This returns 2 result sets and each should look something like this for each returned result set.

```
Table_name      Timestamp                   rec_cnt
--------------------------------------------------
CUSTOMERS     2015-09-24 13:10:01.1770000     378
```

I have tried a few things but can't get the syntax correct.

Thanks for any pointers.
Pat

Comment: You need a space before Group By. `' Group By...'`

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CountStar 
    @Tabname SYSNAME    --<-- use appropriate data type for sql server objects
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);

    SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT  @Tabname AS Table_name,ETL_LAST_UPD_DTTM, COUNT(*) 
                   FROM ls.' + QuoteName(@Tabname) +
                   N' GROUP BY ETL_LAST_UPD_DTTM'
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
                      ,N'@Tabname SYSNAME'
                      ,@Tabname 

    SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT @Tabname AS Table_name,ETL_LAST_UPD_DTTM, COUNT(*) 
                   FROM ci.' + QuoteName(@Tabname) +
                  N' GROUP BY ETL_LAST_UPD_DTTM'
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
                      ,N'@Tabname SYSNAME'
                      ,@Tabname 
END
GO
```

Comment: The edited version worked.. had to declare @SQL.. Thanks much!